# How to align a minipage with left page margin?

Tags: minipage

I have a document with a lot of instances where I would like to keep lines of text together. Some of these are lists, as in the example given below. One question is what is the best practice for doing this? I've used `\filbreak` and `\newpage`, but, since I'm constantly editing the chapters, I often, at a later time, end up with breaks where they shouldn't be if I use either.

So, I finally started using minipages. They appear to work fine, except that I need what's inside the minipage to align with what is before and after it. I gather that the minipage has its own margins that are interfering (?). How do I fix this?

Here's a MWE. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item If I pull the trigger, Abe Lincoln will die.
\item I do not pull the trigger.
\item Therefore, Abe Lincoln will not die.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{2mm}

\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Abe Lincoln was either from France or from Luxembourg.
\item Abe Lincoln was not from Luxembourg.
\item Therefore, Abe Lincoln was from France.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-2mm}
\end{minipage}

\begin{enumerate}
\item If the world were to end today, then I would not need to get up tomorrow morning.
\item I will need to get up tomorrow morning.
\item Therefore, the world will not end today.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\noindent` before `\begin{minipage}`.  No blank line between.

Comment: `minipage` is positioned the same way as a letter, it has no built in margins

Comment: Ah, there we go. Awesome. Thank you.